# What should I do if I don't have enough reputation to vote to close a question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

If a question can be resolved trivially because the issue is a typographical error, or something similar, but I don't have enough reputation to vote to close, what can I do?

I thought of these options:

1. Flag as Very Low Quality. Maybe it could be classified under "content problems".
2. Flag in need of moderator intervention. This feels a bit extreme.
3. Comment with the solution and then ask the OP to delete the question, explaining that this question will only add clutter to the site. I feel this may be the best option, since it also educates the OP.

Comment: The options for flagging for closure are the same as the options for voting to close, just flag it for closure for the appropriate reason.

Comment: @Servy Are you saying that either option 1 or 2 would be appropriate?

Comment: flag -> should be closed... -> off-topic because... -> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**...

Comment: Servy is saying to use the flag option "should be closed..." Which will take you to a list of _other_ flagging options. Choose the appropriate option from there. In the flag dialog, any option ending in "..." will take you to a sub menu when you select it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If a question can be resolved trivially because the issue was a syntax error

We already have a close reason for this. You can flag as off-topic with this reason (emphasis added):

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or ***a simple typographical error***. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

To access this reason, click **flag** > **should be closed...** > **off-topic because...**.